# Where should be the QtCreator plugins path?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

After installing Qt.Creator I got the following error:

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".

Reading the error message it's look like Qt don't know where search the platform plugin. So my question is how can I help QtCreator to found the plugins path.

What I already checked :

- plugins and platforms directory exists.
- qwindowsd.dll exist.

Comment: I met the same issue at 5.3.1 after move Qt to another disk, reinstall solves it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't change anything for me :/

Comment: If the directory exists, try to add it to the PATH env variable. restart the computer and try again

Comment: It's work ! Thank you =D